# why would you wrap a variable in square brackets? php 7

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6

So I'm in the need of format an existing library to be accepted in a web app that is currently working with PHP 5.6 and the library is in PHP 7 (I know this isn't the best practice but they do not want to upgrade to PHP 7 yet and to my demise, they won't budge) so I was wondering what is the use of the square brackets around a variable? it is written into something like:

```
$language = $locale = strtolower($locale);
if (strpos($locale, '_') !== false) {
    [$language] = explode('_', $locale);
}
```

what is the use of it? does it do anything special? I've been searching in the PHP manual but couldn't find a lot

Comment: It's the PHP 7.1 syntax for `list($language) = explode('_', $locale);`

Comment: THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS